# R studio g++ issue

Tags: r, g++, rstan

Actually when I am running my script it is giving me the attached error.
Have tried reinstalling the rstan package and check permissions but the issue is still there.

On the screenshot it is saying g++ file isn't there but when I have checked it is there but its content are quite unreadible.

Error which I am getting on while executing this line on console

```
BasicModel6 = stan(file = "Zuricmodel.stan", data = list(nAgents = nAgents,
```

```
> sh: /home/Zuric/gcc5/bin/g++ -std=c++1y -fPIC: No such file or directory
The NEXT version of Stan will not be able to pre-process your Stan program.
Please open an issue at
 https://github.com/stan-dev/stanc3/issues 
if you can share or at least describe your Stan program. This will help ensure that Stan
continues to work on your Stan programs in the future. Thank you!
This message can be avoided by wrapping your function call inside suppressMessages().
Error in dyn.load(libLFile) : 
  unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpCJz6BL/file44e0333f2bb3.so':
  /tmp/RtmpCJz6BL/file44e0333f2bb3.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5rstan8stan_fitC1EP7SEXPRECi
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system2(CXX, args = ARGS) : error in running command
2: In file.remove(c(unprocessed, processed)) :
  cannot remove file '/tmp/RtmpCJz6BL/file44e075ca3a78.stan', reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection
```

You can find my Makevars file content here.

```
CXX14 = /home/satmapai/gcc5/bin/g++ -std=c++1y -fPIC
CXX14STD = -std=c++1y -fPIC
CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -std=c++1y -fPIC
CXX14FLAGS+=-flto -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-deprecated-declarations
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++1y -fPIC

#CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -mtune=native -march=native -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -std=c++11 -fPIC
#CXX14 = g++
#CXX14FLAGS+=-flto -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-deprecated-declarations
#CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -fPIC
```

Comment: can you please post the error message as text rather than as a screenshot?  It would also be helpful to see the name of your C++/Stan code file: e.g. does it have spaces or other special characters in the name, or in the path?

Comment: please check now I am also attaching my makeaver file @BenBolker

Comment: @ZainGilani, did you get to the bottom of this? I am having a similar issue, not sure if it is the same cause, but really hoping to get some leads about how to solve my issue…